# Como manipular imagem carregada pelo background: url();

Tags: css, img

Carreguei uma img que ficou muito grande, direto pela folha de estilos css, como diminui-la, pois ela aparece apenas um pedaço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o `background-size: TAMANHO_AQUI;` troque o TAMANHO_AQUI para o tamanho que deseja. Mas isso não é aconselhável, e sim, a sua imagem ser optimizada ja em algum programa de edição de imagens, para o tamanho que você deseja, pôs isso afeta o desempenho de seu site.

Comment: Obrigado, cara vou lembrar desta dica.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulando css:

div {

background: url('fotourl');

background-size: 25%;

border: 2px solid #92b901;

width: 300px;

height: 200px;

}

Neste site ensina várias formas e propriedades para imagens background url css: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Obrigado, mano resolveu meu problema.